# Stylesheet get error as Undefined variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I got notify error like this:

NOTICE: wp-content/themes/aquasize/admin/library/engines/typography-engine.php:66 - Undefined variable: stylesheet

NOTICE: wp-content/themes/aquasize/admin/library/engines/typography-engine.php:70 - Undefined variable: stylesheet

Here my full code:
http://pastebin.com/VsrHzjJ6

This is the line 66 :

```
 preg_match("/\.css/i", $stylesheet, $matches);
```

This is the line 70:

```
  if( $stylesheet ) wp_enqueue_style( $font, $stylesheet, 1, 2 );
```

I try to fixed but failed on the newest PHP version. Really appreciate for all your help.
Thanks

Comment: these are notices and warnings not errors.
Either define the variable, or turn error reporting for notices off.

Comment: My problem is: I always failed to define the variable. I'm new in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding:

```
/**
 * This will log all errors notices and warnings to a file called debug.log in
 * wp-content (if Apache does not have write permission, you may need to create
 * the file first and set the appropriate permissions (i.e. use 666) )
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

near the top in your wp-config.php file on your development install.

**Updated**

these are notices and warnings not errors. Either define the variable, or turn error reporting for notices off.

Please try to define it on top of code  for globally. Or define out side the calling function.

```
$stylesheet= "";
```

Comment: Thanks, but that code only hide the error. Not fixed the main problem.

Comment: Hope you get solved your problem